# How to set password to staging env for a django app on Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku

I'd like to password-protect my staging environment so it's not accessible to the public. Also, the password protection should not be tied to Django's authentication backend, so that I can test features (e.g. creating an account for user, logging in / out, etc.).
How best to achieve that?

Comment: 1. simply google your question. 2. don't worry so much as long you are in the testing phase. People don't even know the url of your site. So its pretty hard to hack and what is even more important: nobody wants to hack you.

Comment: I only ask questions on SO if I don't find an answer on Google. how about if you're not going to help to not comment at all.

Comment: I was not rude and Im not the one who down voted your question. I think that was a normal comment. Sorry if you felt offended.

Comment: Great example of "biting the hand that feeds you".

Answer (score 1):

So here are some ideas:

1. Do not make a registration possible. No form, no form validation etc
2. Give users you created special profile attributes like `is_real_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)` or maybe a group. Check or uncheck the boolean in the admin only!
3. Check in the views, templates, forms etc if the user has the attribute `is_real_user` and if not send `404/Validation_error`
4. The first view on your "homepage" (start page) can have a `form` where user needs to type in password(s). Do a form validation and if its `True` render next template `else` `404/Validation_error` and redirect him again to the main page.
5. Save in session/userprofile that the password was correct and check on templates/views if the correct password is given (again `Booleanfield`) else `404/Validation_error`
6. Do not tell anybody about your site, url.

Hope that helps a bit :)

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the ideas, sorry if I was rude.

Comment: No problem, I totally understand the frustration when the code does not run as expected and you go to SO to get some help ;)